# Text number format is not working in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to change the number format of a column of an excel file to TEXT format using PHPExcel library.I tried the code given below, but it is not working:

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column)->getNumberFormat()
   ->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
```

Comment: So what is the value in the cell, and how do you want to see it displayed?